# SOQL querying ID's only returning first result

Tags: apex, soql, fields, custom

I have a custom object called "Call_List__c" which has a field named "Call_List_Members__c". This field has a list of Contact Id's separated by commas.

In an apex class, I split the "Call_List_Members__c" field into a list and then I'm doing an SOQL query to pull the all of the contact records from the list.

Please see code below:

```
List<String> contactIds = new List<String>(); 
contactIds = callList[0].Call_List_Members__c.split(',');

List<Contact> callListMembers = [
  SELECT Id, Name, Title, Department, Phone, Email
  FROM Contact
  WHERE Id IN :contactIds
];

return callListMembers;
```

The problem here is that when I return the callListMembers query, there is only one result. Is there something that I've overlooked here? I want to return all of the records based on the ID's in the Call List Members field.

Comment: Are your Ids actually delimited by a comma and a space?

Comment: Yes, below is a copypaste of the field's contents

0037F00000D3QJQ, 0037F00000D3QJU, 0037F00000D3QJH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to strip the whitespace from your Ids before you can query for them. Apex checks this for you when you write Ids literally in a query:

```
System.debug([SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Id IN (' 0033600001aXXXXAAI')]);
```

> SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Id IN (' 0033600001aXXXXAAI') ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:30 invalid ID field: 0033600001aXXXXAAI

but it does *not* when you bind a collection:

```
Set<String> ids = new Set<String>{' 003000000000001'};
System.debug([SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :ids]);
```

> 20:13:06:009 USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|()

Instead, it just returns no results. To avoid this, you'll have to iterate over the collection and use the `trim()` method to remove whitespace from the start and end of your Ids.

Alternately, you can skip around the issue by passing a regex to `split()`:

```
for (String s :'0037F00000D3QJQ, 0037F00000D3QJU, 0037F00000D3QJH'.split('\\s*,\\s*')) 
    System.debug('\'' +s + '\'');
```

> 20:18:52:002 USER_DEBUG [1]|DEBUG|'0037F00000D3QJQ'
>
> 20:18:52:002 USER_DEBUG [1]|DEBUG|'0037F00000D3QJU'
>
> 20:18:52:002 USER_DEBUG [1]|DEBUG|'0037F00000D3QJH'

The regex eats the interstitial spaces as part of the delimiter, but note that it will *not* remove any leading or trailing space on the overall string.